# Can you tell k8s to deploy based on a git revision? What options are there

Tags: kubernetes

Normally I would use ansible to deploy my code to a server.

Using k8s, what options are there?

Since everything is in a container, I guess the best practice is for immutable deployments as oppose to updating the code on a running instance?

Is it possible to just update the git revision # in your .yaml file and you can make it so it pulls from a specific version to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Set up Jenkins to build Docker containers of every app from their Git repos. Make it tag the images with Git revisions or whatever (I like commit number). Make it push images to your Docker private registry.

Put all *.yaml of the cluster into a Git repository. Commit-push changes to these configs. On the cluster end - pull-apply.

Answer (score -1):

https://helm.sh/ can help you.

---

Here are the steps you need to take:

- Package your app(yaml with image tag as template parameter) as a Helm chart `<your-helm-chart>`.
- Your chart's `values.yaml` (input to yaml template) will have one parameter `git_commit_id: <some-id>`
- Your yaml template takes image tag parameter: `image: your-app:{{ .Values.git_commit_id }}`, this comes from `values.yaml`.
- you will deploy your app as `helm install <your-helm-chart>`, this will give you a `<release name>`.
- and then later when you need to update with new image tag: `helm upgrade <release-name> <your-helm-chart> --set git_commit_id=NEWID`

Comment: But who will actually pull the code from git, and compile it if necessary?

Comment: One option would be your git repository on a new commit triggering your CI/CD server ( like Jenkins) , which will then compile & build image push it to hub, and then uppdate your deployment on Kubernetes. ( You can also extrapolate this idea on how to trigger Ansible, I'm not familiar with it)